# Find all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4$ of order $4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I know that

$$ \mathbb{Z}_2 = \{0, 1\} \\ \mathbb{Z}_4 = \{0, 1, 2, 3\} $$

Then

$$
\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4 = \{ (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (1,1), (1,2), (1,3) \}
$$

We want to find all subgroups of this with order 4. By Lagrange's theorem, the order of every subgroup must divide the order of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$, namely 7. Thus each subgroup must have order of 1. Therefore, no subgroup exists with order 4.

Is this correct?

Comment: What about $(1,0)$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner $(1, 0) = (0, 1)$ according to OP, I guess.

Comment: Be careful -- $\mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/4$ has order 8, not 7

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Is the exterior direct sum just all permutations of the elements? I was considering only the combinations

Comment: The underlying set is the cartesian product, so we have $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ as distinct elements. Indeed the size of $G \oplus H$ is the size of $G$ times the size of $H$ for this reason

Comment: And for completeness, the operation is $(a,b) + (c,d) = (a+c, b+d)$

Comment: Ok so by Lagrange's theorem each subgroup must have order 1, 2, or 4. How do I go about finding the subgroups? Do I have to check the group axioms for each combination of 4 elements from $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: Well, you know that $\mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2$ and $\mathbb{Z}/4$ are the ONLY groups of order $4$. Can you find either (or both...) of those groups living inside $\mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/4$?

Comment: After you've found these groups, ask yourself if there can be any others. There will be a couple ways to argue that there cannot be any more

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the Subgroups of $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_4$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666840/what-are-the-subgroups-of-bbbz-2-times-bbbz-4)

Answer (score 1):

> By Lagrange's theorem, the order of every subgroup must divide the order of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$, namely 7.

The order of $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4$ **is not** $7$, it is $8$. Remember that for the Cartesian product we have

$$|X\times Y|=|X|\cdot |Y|$$

And the direct sum "$\oplus$" is just the Cartesian product as a set.

Note that you missed $(1,0)$ when you've listed elements from $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4$.

---

Back to the problem. So you are looking for all subgroups of order $4$. In general there is no easy way to approach this. Fortunately $G$ is a small and not that complicated group.

There are only two (up to isomorphism) groups of order $4$: $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

**(1)** Let's find all subgroups of $G$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is cyclic then we are looking for elements in $G$ of order $4$. But in the direct product we have a nice formula:

$$o(g,h)=lcm(o(g), o(h))$$

In our situation this means that all we need is an element $h\in\mathbb{Z}_4$ of order $4$ and any element $g\in\mathbb{Z}_2$. Then the cyclic group generated by $(g,h)$ will be a subgroup of order $4$. This gives us following two solutions:

$$H_1=\langle(0,1)\rangle=\{(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3)\}$$
$$H_2=\langle(1,1)\rangle=\{(0,0), (1,1), (0,2), (1,3)\}$$

Note that there are more elements of order $4$. For example $(1,3)$ but $\langle(1,1)\rangle=\langle(1,3)\rangle$.

**(2)** Now let's find all subgroups of $G$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$. There is one obvious solution

$$K=\{(0,0), (1,0), (0,2), (1,2)\}$$

Are there any other? The answer is no. That is because any element not from $K$ is of order $4$. Thus no subgroup containing it can be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$.

**All in all:** $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4$ has $3$ subgroups of order $4$.